# Best way to visualize a graph and voronoi diagram in c++

Tags: c++, graphics

I am writing a program to compute the k-means clustering of a pointset.  I want to visualize the steps, so to save a picture of each step in jpg or png form.  It would also be nice to save a picture of the Voronoi diagram at the end, as well.

What is the best tool for drawing and saving an image of a graph, given the edges and vertices?  Coloured vertices would be a plus

Answer (score 2):

Two really useful tools for visualising data that I use often are graphviz http://www.graphviz.org/ and gnuplot http://www.gnuplot.info/. Graphviz is great for undirected and directed graphs. Gnuplot is great for 2D lines and points. Look at the examples on the websites will give you an idea what you can do with them.

They both have text file formats that are really easy to produce from your program. You can either write a plain text file and convert it to an image file after your program has run. Or you can open a pipe to the program and set the output file and type.

As a side note Graphviz graphs can be embedded in doxygen comments which makes for a neat way put graphs into your documentation. You didn't ask but I am writing some documentation at the moment so it is on my mind.

Comment: Very cool, thanks.  Do you know if graphviz has voronoi diagram capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to visualize your Voronoi diagram would be to write out an SVG file. Edges would become `<line>` elements, vertices (and the midpoints in Voronoi diagrams) would become `<circle>` elements. Different elements can be colored differently, too. You would have to determine the size of the diagram beforehand, though. Advantage of this method is that you don't need a fancy library to write out an image, and the SVG can be shown in IE or Firefox.